# Algorithm to find the sum of all contiguous substrings of a set

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

Im trying to write a time efficient algorithm that can find that sum of all of the possible **contiguous** substring of an array (preserving order and combinations can be any length)

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4] -> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 12 + 23 + 34 + 123 + 234 + 1234 = 1670
```

It is also important to note that the array can repeat itself multiple times

My best attempt so far is probably this: (n is the set of numbers)

```
k = 3 // number of times the array repeats
length = len(n)
total = 0

for i in range(0, length*k):
    for exp in range(0, length*k-i): 
    //iterate though all of the possible powers of ten a certain number could be in
    // ie. all the different places that number could be in for all combinations 

        total += ((n[i % length] * 10**exp) * (i + 1))
        // ^ turns number from standard from into int. The i + 1 account for
        // the fact the number could be in the same position in more than one combination

return total
```

However, this algorithm has to run for an array with over 10^20 numbers in it, so I am looking for a faster algorithm.

Note that all numbers are single digits and the digits can repeat

Comment: did you try itertools.combinations?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic I considered it but the array is too larger for the whole thing to be used - I get a memory error. It repeats multiple times so I only use the unrepeated section

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Ive updated my code to reflect this

Comment: 10^20 numbers? Where did you get a computer with over 100 exabytes of memory?

Comment: @Thomas Ive updated the question to reflect that fact that the array repeats itself. If I could work with all of the numbers at once it would be simple to brute force every combination but I am only working that one segment that is 10^6 numbers long (so it repeats approximately 10^14 times)

Comment: Your example doesn't show "combinations", it shows substrings.

Comment: What about the combinations `[2,4], [1,3,4]`, etc?

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry I should have stated that the subsets must be contiguous

Comment: How do you sum arrays? Do you mean 1234 + 123 + 234 + ... ? In this case the longest number has at least n digits! This seems to be pretty crazy.

Comment: @maraca the longest combination will simply be the entire set. It is probably better to describe these as substrings

Comment: @maraca I believe it to be 1670, I changed the question to better reflect the problem

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, each element is a single-digit integer

Comment: @Ronikos thanks I understood now, very tricky problem. Check out O(n) version that calculates the result for numbers of any length in a single iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the [generalized version](https://jsfiddle.net/2ut7nthz/) in O(n), which works for positive numbers of any length:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = solve([1,2,3,4]) + " = 1670<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += solve([22,101,3]) + " = " + (22+101+3+22101+1013+221013);

function solve(arr) {
    let n = arr.length, total = 0, sum = 0;
    for (let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        total += arr[i] * (i + 1) * (sum + 1);
        let f = Math.pow(10, len(arr[i]));
        sum = f + sum * f;
    }
    return total;
}

function len(x) {
    if (x < 10)
        return 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.log10(x)) + 1;
}
```

I came up with the formula by writing out the equations for `n-1` to `n-3`:

```
n-1: a[n-1] * n
n-2: a[n-2] * (n-1) + a[n-2] * (n-1) * 10^len(a[n-1])
n-3: a[n-3] * (n-2) + a[n-3] * (n-2) * (10^len(a[n-2]) + 10^(len(a[n-1]) + len(a[n-2])))
```

The first term expresses how many times the number is in the last position. We denote the sum of the `10^...` parts as `sum` and factor out `a[i] * (i+1)`, that's where the `+1` comes from in `*(sum+1)`. The `sum` for the next iteration is `10^len(a[i])+10^len(a[i])*sum`. This is because
 `10^a + 10^a * (10^b + 10^(b+c) + ...) = 10^a + 10^(a+b) + 10^(a+b+c) + ...`.

Answer (score 3):

We can count the number of appearances of any given element at any given power of 10 by noting the number of possible start (left) and end (right) positions for a subarray containing that element.

The number of starting positions is simply the number of elements to the left (+1) and the number of ending positions is simply the number of elements to the right (+1). For example, subarrays containing `6` in `[4,5,6,7]` will have 3 starting positions and 2 end positions:

```
s s s e e
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
[4,5,6,7]
```

Starting positions will not affect the power of 10 an element appears at - `456`, `56` and `6` shows 3 different starting positions for subarrays containing the element `6`, but for all of them `6` is at 10<sup>0</sup>. The number of possible starting positions will be a direct multiplier for how often an element can appear at a position (3 starting positions -> can appear at each position 3 times).

Ending positions affect the power of 10 an element appears at, but not the number of times it appears there: `5`, `56` and `567` shows 3 ending positions for subarrays containing the element `5`. `5` appears at 10<sup>0</sup>, 10<sup>1</sup> and 10<sup>2</sup>, each time once only. We can sum this up using `5*111`.

Putting these 2 things together, the effect on the sum any element would have is:

```
element * start positions * 111...(end positions times)...11
```

As implied above, `start positions` is 1 + the current index (0-based arrays). And `end positions` decreases by 1 as we move from the left to the right of the array (or increases by 1 as we move right to left), so, for the right-most term above, we can start off from the right with `1` and just multiply by 10 and add 1 repeatedly.

This leads to some rather simple (Java) code:

```java
int[] array = {1,2,3,4};
int sum = 0;
int endMultiplier = 0;
for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    endMultiplier = 10*endMultiplier + 1;
    sum += array[i] * (i+1) * endMultiplier;
}
System.out.println(sum); // prints 1670
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/naSnjj)

---

**If elements can be multiple digits**, the above approach can be generalised by, instead of multiplying `endMultiplier` by 10, we multiply it based on the length of the current element (10 for length 1, 100 for length 2, etc.).

```java
int endMultiplier = 1;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sum += array[i] * (i+1) * endMultiplier;
    // Direct method of calculating k (with floating points):
    // int k = array[i] == 0 ? 10 : (int)Math.pow(10, 1+(int)Math.log10(array[i]));
    int k = 10;
    for (; k < array[i]; k *= 10)
        {}
    endMultiplier = k*endMultiplier + 1;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/9bv6Jo).

Comment: Only works for arrays with single digit numbers, e.g. not [22, 101, 3].

Comment: @maraca Updated answer with a more general approach, although the question does state elements are single digits.

Comment: Right, now I finally saw it. My reading comprehension is failing me lately. +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can:
1) find  `n[i]  * (i + 1)` once per i-iteration
2) find sum of `1+10 + 100 + ...10^(length-i-1)` as sum of arithmetic progression

```
  s = 10^(length-i) - 1 / 9
  9999..99/9=1111..11
```

So you can get O(n) complexity.

3) more optimization - make `1111...` multiplier with single operation per i- iteration (integer divide initial value by 10 or make `m*10+1` for reversed loop)